# Why does multiplication in VHDL sometimes not work as expected with an integer?

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL with strong typing when doing multiplication I'd expect the following statement to end up with a 14 bit output:

```vhdl
frame_addr  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(13 downto 0);

...

signal  y_pos       : unsigned(4 downto 0);

...

frame_addr <= std_logic_vector(y_pos * 320);
```

But I end up with the error:

`expression has 10 elements, but must have 14 elements`

Which makes NO sense to me... As 320 should be at-least 9 bits as an unsigned, 10 as an integer, and when multiplied with the 5 bit signal y_pos I'd expect to see AT-LEAST 14 bits...

I have another section of code where this works out PERFECTLY FINE:

```vhdl
ram_addr <= std_logic_vector(h_pos + (v_pos * 80))(14 downto 0);
```

The multiplication with 80 works just fine, no errors.

So I tried everything to get up to 14 bits... and of-course the multiplication just appears to NOT happen when in my logic...
So I finally said, OK what if I just do multiplication with BINARY tell it exactly what I want...

```vhdl
frame_addr <= std_logic_vector(y_pos * "101000000");
```

Compiles fine with no errors...
And the logic starts working as I would expect it to.

So why is there this inconsistency? Both of these are within an architecture structure for relevance, not within processes or anything like that.
I just can't wrap my head around why there are these inconsistencies...
Both use the same libraries:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
```

So what gives? Do I have to use binary anywhere I want a number for any kind of code consistency?

Comment: From package numeric_std - `function "*" (L: UNSIGNED; R: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED is begin return L * TO_UNSIGNED(R, L'LENGTH);
  end "*";` where two unsigned multiplied together has a result length that is the sum of the operand lengths. Also note 320 requires 9 bits of accuracy which would result in needing the left operand to be 9 bits and a result of 18 bits. You're better off converting a larger magnitude natural value to an unsigned with a length sufficient to hold the binary numeric value.

Comment: Your PERFECTLY FINE example shouldn't work, whose tool (and version)? You can't slice an expression whose prefix isn't a name or a function call (IEEE Std 1076-2008  8. Names, 8.1 General). A type conversion isn't a function call it's a basic operation (5. Types, 5.1 General) and the prefix must be appropriate for a one-dimensional array object  (8.5 Slice names). "An *object* is a named entity that contains (has) a value of a type." (6.4 Objects, 6.4.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because integer has no bitwise length, it is converted to the same length as y_pos. So in your first example, Y_pos is 5 bits. so 320 gets converted to a unsigned also of 5 bits - giving a 10 bit result. This rule is the same for all of the arithmetic operators for signed and unsigned.

Integers in VHDL have no bitwise definition, and so need to be converted somehow. The compiler cannot do intelligent sizing, so relies on the user to size it properly. In your example, 320 getting converted to 5 bits clearly truncates the value, and you would actually end up with "00000" and a warning that this is happening during simulation.

There is no inconsistency here, "101000000" and 320 are completely different and unrelated types. Unsigned is not an integer - it is a binary representation of an unsigned integer.

You probably want to use the to_unsigned() function on your integer literals to get an explicit size:

```
frame_addr <= std_logic_vector(y_pos * to_unsigned(320, 9));
```

Comment: Your first statement ("... both operands are converted to the length of the longest operand") is inaccurate. Package numeric_std (-2008) `function "*" (L, R : UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED) return UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED is`...`variable RESULT : UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED((L'length+R'length-1) downto 0) := (others => '0');` Here the length of the result is the sum of the lengths of the operands for example. You've also misspelled  arithmetic in your haste.